# C# How to Manage Many Threads, Mostly Waiting on Response from Databases

Tags: c#, database, multithreading, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have 24 threads that do very little work outside of making database calls.

I separate my data set into groupings based on the database I want to query (there's 24 databases total). I then make a thread for each grouping.

```
List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();
foreach (var collection in groupedCollections)
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(() => myService.MakeDBCalls(collection.ToList());
    thread.Start();
    threads.Add(thread);
}
```

Inside each thread, I make a database call, do very basic processing, and then repeat for the entire group.

If my application is single threaded, the latency for my database calls take `.015s` (I measure with `DateTime.Now`). Once I ramp up to 24 threads, my database calls take up to `.3` seconds.

My suspicion is that the threads are blocking each other. However, my CPU is mostly idle, because the threads are `99%` of the time waiting on the response from the database.

Is there a sensible way to make the thread sleep until it is triggered by a response from the database?

Comment: could you use a `Task` instead...

Comment: Is a task not a thread behind the scenes?

Comment: not always. but it is a cleaner abstraction. you could look into async/await.

Comment: Are you suggesting I make 24 tasks, or are you suggesting that I wrap the DB call within each thread with a Task/Wait?

Comment: it depends how you are calling the database - theres many patterns.

Comment: What's your hardware setup and network topology?  In other words, what physical machines do you have, how are they connected, and where are you running those 24 databases?

Comment: Spawning new threads like that seems a bit odd. Using System.Threading.Tasks.Task along with async/await is probably the best thing you can do in most cases.

Comment: I am spawning threads like this because of my grouping strategy (I'm not suggesting it's correct).  The reason I do groupings like I have done is because each grouping is intended for separate database entirely (group 1 goes to server 1, group 2 goes to server 2... etc).

Comment: @MikeNakis 24 SQL instances on separate servers in a colo about 3 miles from my current location where my application is being run.

Comment: _because the threads are 99% of the time waiting on the response from the database._ - Very good sign to not waste threads for this then - check `async-await` approach for working with IO resources in one thread manner

Comment: Guys, async-await is cool, it is awesome, but still it won't make a bit of a difference here.

Comment: That is very strange to have such huge latency increase in this case. Maybe you should add the code of how you are actually making and measuring those calls. I doubt async/await will make any difference here really.

Comment: @MikeNakis why would that be ?

Comment: @MikeNakis - big difference from using thread resources. As OP mentioned already threads so nothing - only waiting for response. `async-await` give possibility to "wait" for response without wasting threads

Comment: @Evk for Database calls, async await based concurrency is anyway the ideal mechanism, that can surely not have a negative impact. Beside other required optimizations.

Comment: @MrinalKamboj because a) the threads are too few to cause any problems, b) the threads are constantly running, not created and destroyed, c) the issue here is latency, not throughput.

Comment: _I measure with DateTime.Now_ - try measure with `Stopwatch`, which will use more precise techniques

Comment: @MrinalKamboj that's for sure, I just mean it will unlikely to solve the problem.

Comment: @MikeNakis True but threads are always an overhead for such a scenario, where all that they do is dispatch the call and wait for it to return. Better get rid of unnecessary contention

Comment: Just as a note, I'd also use a `Parallel.ForEach` here instead of just a `foreach` statement, especially if you add more work within the loop.

Comment: To OP: try to run different number of threads (2,4,6,8 etc) and see which effect this has on the latency.

Comment: please keep us posted with the outcome of this.

Comment: @MikeNakis I will.  Downside is that I can only run my tests outside of business hours.

Comment: @MikeNakis Following up on this.  We ran the test on-prem and discovered that the extra latency was due to the bandwidth limitations between on-prem and my machine.  24 threads (mostly waiting) was not a factor in the increased latencies.  The fact that we were pulling 24x the information *was*.

Comment: Good to hear that you found what the cause was!

Comment: (The "single ethernet cable, through which you are passing not only your database requests, but also your incoming results" that I wrote about.)

Comment: Yep.  You hit the nail on the head when you mentioned network topology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably running on a machine with way fewer than 24 cores, so a tiny bit of the additional latency comes from thread contention, but not much, because as you have seen, your CPU is mostly idle.

However:

- if your databases are on the same machine as your processing threads, then all this software is querying data that ultimately reside on a single disk connected to your motherboard via a single SATA cable.
- if your databases are on different machines, then consider that your processing threads are running on a machine connected to the rest of the world through a single ethernet cable, through which you are passing not only your database requests, but also your incoming results.  Then, your database servers live somewhere, and I bet you don't have 24 different physical machines for them, so some of them share the same hardware, most importantly the same disk.

What I am trying to get at is that even though CPU does not appear to be a contented resource, there are always other resources that your threads contend for.

At the end of the day, 24 channels of parallelization for a per-channel slowdown of only 100% is pretty good; you should consider yourself lucky.

Comment: "Single ethernet cable" was indeed the issue.  Too little bandwidth.  CPU's 4 cores were handling the 24 threads just fine.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a sensible way to make the thread sleep until it is triggered by a response from the database?

Most sensible way would be to not use the threads at all, instead use `Async` APIs to make the `Db` calls, which is an `IO` call, which can be `awaited`, without involving any thread and thus even introducing the `concurrency` as desired. This is most efficient concurrency option for `IO / Remote service calls`, for which threads shall not be wasted.

> If Async APIs are not available ?

This would be rare for database client (which client do you use?), but then you may use `TPL` to wrap them in `Task`, which will source threads from `Threadpool` and would still be much more efficient than invoking separate threads. However, this still means wasting threads from the pool.

> Remember

`Async-Await` is ideal, for this it needs complete call chain to be `Async` enabled for ensuring that caller thread is ceded as the call continue `asynchronously`. You may also consider `ConfigureAwait(false)`, as the continuation may not require the `Synchronization context`.

Answer (score 0):

If your client allows, do connect to database in `async` fashion, so your threads wouldn't starve like they are do now. Still, creating 24 threads isn't a good practice, until you have a server with similar cores available.

If `async` database operations aren't available, you may introduce the [`BlockingCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997371.aspx) for your requests, so you'll get only fixed amount of requests simultaneously.

```
// no more simultaneous tasks than processors available
var dataItems = new BlockingCollection<IList<Data>>(Environment.ProcessorCount);

// if your processing is long enough, consider notifying the scheduler about it
// Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { }, CancellationToken,
//   TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default);

Task.Run(() =>
{
    while (!dataItems.IsCompleted)
    {
        IList<Data> data = null;

        try
        {
            data = dataItems.Take();
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException) { /* completion called */ }

        if (data != null)
        {
            // service call for a taken data
            myService.MakeDBCalls(data);
        }
    }
});

foreach (var collection in groupedCollections)
{
    // Blocks if dataItems.Count == dataItems.BoundedCapacity
    dataItems.Add(collection.ToList());
}

// Let consumer know we are done.
dataItems.CompleteAdding();
```